# dereferencing freed pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, free

```
int** array = (int**) malloc(1*sizeof(int*));
int* int_in_array = (int*) malloc(1*sizeof(int));
*int_in_array = 6
array[0] = int_in_array;
```

and suppose I do

```
free(array)
```

can I still rely on the fact that `*int_in_array` will give me 6?

Now suppose in addition, I do

```
free(array[0])
```

then, can I still rely on the fact that `*int_in_array` will give me 6 since `int_in_array` still points to 6?

thanks so much!

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: @unwind You should cast the return value of `malloc()` because it returns a `void *`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to somehow have a mental model where you expect pointers to be magically supervised, so that one pointer shold "know" what happens to another.

That's not how pointers, or the C memory model, work at all.

There is no connection between different pointers. If two pointers point at the same address, and you `free()` one of them, the other one becomes invalid *but it's value doesn't change*. Neither does the value of the first; it's just that dereferencing either of them just became an invalid thing to do.

Consider this:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);

if(a != NULL)
{
  int *b = a;
  *a = 4711;

  printf("a=%p\nb=%p\n", (void *) a, (void *) b);
  free(b);  /* same pointer that malloc() returned, this is fine */
  printf("a=%p\nb=%p\n", (void *) a, (void *) b);
}
```

The above will print the same address four times, since the value of any of the pointers doesn't change just because you call `free()` on one of them. Remember that `free()` is not magic, it's just a function. There is no special hidden functionality with it, you can write your own `malloc()` and `free()` if you feel like it and get the exact same semantics.

Answer (score 0):

```
int** array = (int**) malloc(1*sizeof(int*));
int* int_in_array = (int*) malloc(1*sizeof(int));
*int_in_array = 6
array[0] = int_in_array;
```

after doing `free(array)` you can still access and use `int_in_array`. But you cannot call `free(array[0])` afterwards because you cannot use `array` any more.

If you don't call `free(array)` but just `free(array[0])`, you cannot use `*int_in_array` because you freed the memory.

Answer (score 0):

1. `6` is stored in the memory that is pointed to by `int * int_in_array`. 
   So if you `free()` this memory (by doing `free(int_in_array)`) the `6` is gone, or at least not accessible anymore without provoking undefined behavior.
2. In the memory that is pointed to by `array` a copy of the value of `int_in_array` is stored. So `free()`ing this copy by calling `free(array)` does not affect what is stored in `int_in_array`. And also in no way the memory this value points to is affected.
   The data pointed to by array can be accessed directly by either doing `*array` or by doing `array[0]`. As it stores the copy of `int_in_array` doing `free(array[0]` is the same as doing `free(int_in_array)`. with the same results on accessing `6` as mentioned under 1.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `free(array)`, `int_in_array` is still guaranteed to point to a piece of memory containing `6`. `array` itself may or may not continue pointing to `int_in_array` depending on whether the memory it used to occupy was needed somewhere else, or a whole host of other circumstances.

When you call `free(int_in_array)`, you are telling the system that you do not require the memory containing `6` any longer. The pointer value will still be the same, but you are no longer guaranteed that `6` will still be the value stored at that location.